# Notebook not found error for .ipynb file in Github

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipynb

I'm trying to upload a `ipynb` file in vs code to my GitHub repo; however, I cannot see the file preview. I see only the "notebook not found" error.

I try to upload file from collab or try to use `nbviewer`(in `nbviewer` I got this error "404 :

```
Not Found Remote HTTP 404: Not Found ({
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
})")
```

but nothing solves this problem. I deleted the repo and opened it again then uploaded it however, there was still no change.

I can't see the same problem anywhere that's why I want to ask if anyone knows how I can solve this problem.

Edit: I can see the code in github btw but preview still not working?

```
    {
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 1,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "hello World\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "print('hello World')"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "base",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".ipynb",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.11.5"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 2
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a question to GitHub support.

Comment: What is the URL of the .ipynb file on github.com?

Comment: https://github.com/berkeceylan/StepCountPrediction-Project/blob/main/StepCountPredictionProject_ipynp.ipynb

Comment: That's a HTTP 404 error for me. You may want to change the repository to public on github.com.

Comment: actually it was public I double checked I will provide code again 
https://github.com/berkeceylan/StepCountPrediction-Project/blob/main/StepCountPredictionProject_ipynp.ipynb?short_path=e1cc7fa

Comment: The link is still broken. Even this link is HTTP 404 error for me: https://github.com/berkeceylan/StepCountPrediction-Project ; please double check your links and repository permissions

Comment: It seems github flagged my account and therefore no one see my repos even they are public. ı open a ticket I hope it will be fixed